# Python - how to insert to a tk.Listbook inside a class that inherited tk.Listbook class?

Tags: listbox

```
class SelectionBox(tk.Listbox):
""" 
"""

def __init__(self, parent,data):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self._data = data
```

and some relevant part from other class:

```
self._animal_data_sets = tk.Frame(master)
self._selection_box = SelectionBox(self._animal_data_sets,self._data)
```

I can insert a listbox inside the main class (the last code), but I want to insert the listbox inside the first class.
How to do it?

I've tried `self.insert`, `super().insert`, etc. and they did not work.